# How to do shell variable replacement in gnu make

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

Here is a simplified Makefile yet exposes the same problem as I am facing:

```
all:
        for i in *.pod; do g=${i%%.pod}; echo ${g};done
```

What I want is get the file names without the postfix. But when I run the make, I see this:

```
for i in *.pod; do g=; echo ;done
```

It seems to me the dollar replacement in shell is trimmed away totally.

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Do you actually want to echo several filenames without the suffix, or do you want to do general variable replacement in a shell command?

Comment: In order to avoid make interpreting a `$` as indicating substitutiοn, you need to double it `$$`.

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern substitutions should suffice (make sure to use tabs):

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.pod)
BIN = $(patsubst %.pod;,%,$(SRC))

all: 
         echo $(BIN)
```

Answer (score 0):

make expands all `$(something)` and `${something}` it finds and replaces them with the value of the **make** variable `something`. So, if you want to use shell variables and prevent make from expanding them, simply double the `$` sign (if it is subject to one single make expansion, else you need more `$` signs). In your case:

```
all:
    for i in *.pod; do g=$${i%%.pod}; echo $${g}; done
```

should work.